# Array of Arrays populated with times [hh:mm:ss]

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, timer

How do I create an array of arrays of times in the format [hh:mm:ss]

The array of arrays will consist of each day of the week, and then certain times for each day of the week.

What is the best solution to do this when in the end I am going to compare the current time [hh:mm:ss] with the times in the array [hh:mm:ss] to find the time difference between the next closest time.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would want an NSDictionary of NSArrays, where each entry in the dictionary has a key for the day of the week.  For the array of times, I would simply use NSDate, which will allow you to easily calculate the difference between two times in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could use an NSDictionary of NSArrays containing the times (technically Dates, which contain the time component).  I will show later how to ignore the date portion when comparing the times.

Basically, you will construct an NSArray for each day of the week containing all the times you want for that day.  Then you will add each of those 7 arrays to the NSDictionary with a key for the day of the week (If only did a few of the days, but it should give you the idea:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

// Here are just some dummy times.  The date parts will be ignored in the compare function below.
NSDate *firstTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1970-01-01 07:00:00 +0100"];
NSDate *secondTime   = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1970-01-01 10:19:00 +0100"];
NSDate *thirdTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1970-01-01 15:00:00 +0100"];

// Build our day of the weeek arrays of times.
NSArray *mondayTimes = @[firstTime, secondTime];
NSArray *tuesdayTimes = @[firstTime, thirdTime];
NSArray *wednesdayTimes = @[firstTime, secondTime, thirdTime];

NSDictionary *weekdayTimes = @{@"Monday": mondayTimes, @"Tuesday" : tuesdayTimes, @"Wednesday" : wednesdayTimes };
```

Once you have your NSDictionary, you can retrieve the time arrays from the dictionary through a simple lookup by key, like so:

```
NSArray *tuesdayTimesFromDictionary = [weekdayTimes objectForKey:@"Tuesday"];
```

To compare all the times against the current time, you can simply loop through the array of NSDates and find the one with the lowest time interval since now:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
double minTimeSinceNow = MAXFLOAT;
NSDate *closestTime;
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];

for( NSDate *time in tuesdayTimesFromDictionary)
{
    double timeDiff = [self timeDifferenceBetween:now andDate:time];
    NSLog( [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time compare between to now(%@) and %@ is %f seconds away", [timeFormat stringFromDate:now], [timeFormat stringFromDate:time], timeDiff]);

    if( abs(timeDiff) < minTimeSinceNow)
    {
        minTimeSinceNow = abs(timeDiff);
        closestTime = time;
    }
}

NSLog( [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Closest time to now (%@) is: %@, which is %f seconds away", [timeFormat stringFromDate:now], [timeFormat stringFromDate:closestTime], minTimeSinceNow]);
```

Now, to compare the times only and ignore the dates, I wrote the method called above (`timeDifferenceBetween:andDate:`).  It uses time components to set the date to a common date, but retaining the time:

```
- (double)timeDifferenceBetween:(NSDate *)date1 andDate:(NSDate *)date2
{

    unsigned int flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents* components1 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date1];
    NSDateComponents* components2 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date2];

    NSDate* timeOnly1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components1];
    NSDate* timeOnly2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components2];

    return [timeOnly1 timeIntervalSince1970] - [timeOnly2 timeIntervalSince1970];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful, I am going to try and work on it this weekend and see what I come up with!